# JS Сравнить два массива объектов и получить новый

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

У меня два массива в которых содержатся объекты.

```
allService = [{Name: "Услуга №1", Code: "1", Kind: "Услуга №1"}, {Name: "Услуга №2", Code: "2", Kind: "Услуга №2"}, {Name: "Услуга №6", Code: "6", Kind: "Услуга №6"}, {Name: "Услуга №3", Code: "3", Kind: "Услуга №3"}];
myService = [{Service: '2'}, {Service: '6'}, {Service: '1'}];
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне из массива "allService" получить новый массив "notMyService" в котором будут все услуги за исключением тех что есть в массиве "myService". При условии, что значение Code из массива allService === значению Service из массива myService.

P.S.
Т.е. "allService" это все услуги, "myService" это МОИ услуги, а мне надо получить массив "notMyService" который включает в себя НЕ МОИ услуги.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let allService = [{Name: "Услуга №1", Code: "1", Kind: "Услуга №1"}, {Name: "Услуга №2", Code: "2", Kind: "Услуга №2"}, {Name: "Услуга №6", Code: "6", Kind: "Услуга №6"}, {Name: "Услуга №3", Code: "3", Kind: "Услуга №3"}];
let myService = [{Service: '2'}, {Service: '6'}, {Service: '1'}];

let notMyService = allService.filter(service => myService.every(item => item.Service !== service.Code));

console.log(notMyService);
```

Comment: А не подскажите пожалуйста ещё, как здесь заменить стрелочную функцию? Я так понимаю из-за этого в IE11 не работает...=(

Comment: let notMyService = allService.filter(function(service) { return myService.every(function(item) { return item.Service !== service.Code})});

Answer (score 1):

Например, вот так:

```js
let allService = [
    {Name: "Услуга №1", Code: "1", Kind: "Услуга №1"},
    {Name: "Услуга №2", Code: "2", Kind: "Услуга №2"},
    {Name: "Услуга №6", Code: "6", Kind: "Услуга №6"},
    {Name: "Услуга №3", Code: "3", Kind: "Услуга №3"}
];
let myService = [
    {Service: '2'},
    {Service: '6'},
    {Service: '1'}
];

let services = myService.map(elem => elem.Service);
let servicesSet = new Set(services);
let notMyService = allService.filter(elem => !servicesSet.has(elem.Code));
for (let serv of notMyService)
    console.log(serv.Code);
```